# Call a function on an object and assign the return to the same object at the same time

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I want to convert a series of date strings to `datetime` using the following:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> dataframe.loc[:, 'DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(dataframe.loc[:, 'DATE'])
```

Now, I see `dataframe.loc[:, 'DATE']` as redundant. Is it possible in python that I call a function on an object and assign the return to the same object at the same time?

Something that looks like:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(dataframe.loc[:,'DATE'], +)
```

or

```
dataframe.loc[:,'DATE'] += pd.to_datetime()
```

where `+` (or whatever) assigns the return of the function to its first argument

This question might be due to my lack of understanding on how programming languages are written/function, so please be gentle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such a thing. But you can achieve the same with:

```
name = 'DATE'
dataframe[name] = pd.to_datetime(dataframe[name])
```

No need for `.loc`

Some methods support an `inplace=True` keyword argument.
For example, sorting a dataframe gives you new one:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'DATE': [10, 7, 1, 2, 3]})
>>> df.sort_values()
>>> df.sort_values('DATE')
   DATE
2     1
3     2
4     3
1     7
0    10
```

The original remains unchanged:

```
>>> df
   DATE
0    10
1     7
2     1
3     2
4     3
```

Setting `inplace=True`, modifies the original `df`:

```
>>> df.sort_values('DATE', inplace=True)
>>> df
   DATE
2     1
3     2
4     3
1     7
0    10
```

Comment: @jezrael Thanks for the hint. Added an example.

Comment: sure, glad can help, explanation answers are hard for me, because poor English ;)

Answer (score 1):

Closest Pandas gets to this is the ad-hoc "inplace" command that exists for a good portion of DataFrame functions.

For example, an inplace datetime operation happens to be hidden in the new set_index functionality.

```
df.set_index(df['Date'], inplace=True)
```